# How to retain blank index values in Multilevel index when reading from Excel with Python and pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multi-level

I have an Excel file that looks like the following:
[image]that I'm reading in with pandas as follows:

```
data = pd.read_excel(excelFile,
                     sheetname=sheet,
                     skiprows=[0,1],
                     header=[0],
                     index_col=list(range(0,2)))
```

The problem is that I have blank index values (highlighted in yellow) that pandas ends up filling down with the index column names like so:
[image]
How can I prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired outcome if you fill the empty cells in your file with a space character. Alternatively, you can specify fewer options when reading your file and use simple post-processing:

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel('C:\problem.xlsx', skiprows = [0, 1])

    # Replace NaNs with a space character
    df = df.fillna(' ')

   df = df.set_index(['Description', 'Segment'])

   print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                                  $
    Description         Segment                    
    Total                               1.60528e+08
     Brand A                            3.67197e+07
      Brand A Product 1 Awsome product       107493
      Brand A Product 2 Awsome product
```

Comment: This works for me -- wondering if there's any other solutions before accepting.

Comment: There might be other solutions but I am not aware of them. If you think about it, it doesn't make sense to have NaN in an index column. Therefore, the commands automatically fill the cells with a value.